# Using SQLite database as backend, MS Access for Frontend, more than 2 gigs of data

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, ms-access, frontend

I've been using Microsoft Access for years, but inevitably, I need to move onto other database systems.  Right now, SQLite seems to be perfect for my current work environment.  I understand it's pretty easy to have a SQLite backend with a Microsoft Access frontend.  However, I also know Microsoft Access databases tend to have issues when they exceed 2 gigs. I realize that SQLite is NOT limited to 2 gigs, but if I had say a 10 gig dataset in a SQLite database and used MS Access for the frontend, would I have performance issues? Could it handle it or would it not matter since the backend in on a SQLite database? I apologize for the ignorance in understanding, however, it would be x 10 more ignorant if I kept aimlessly searching for an answer and continued to not find a solution. Thanks!

Comment: If I were talking in GBytes, I would be thinking Postgres or maybe MySQL -- or a version of SQL Server in your case.  However, this is not the place for product recommendations.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the data enigne is quite fast. In fact, on a local machine, you tend to get better performance using JET/ACE as compared to say SQL  server running as a local instance.

It not clear how good or optomized the ODBC drivers are for SQLite, but performance with such a setup should be about as fast as anything else, and likly even faster then running say a local isstance of some type of SQL server. To be fair, because computers often have additional processors (cores), then running a server database even on your local machine can yield better performance since you are using "more" processors to do the same job.

Ignoring the threading issue (JET/ACE and SQLite are NOT threaded to my knowledge, and thus you can't really take advantage of multiple CPU cores.

However, from a raw performance point of view, I suspect that SQLite is slower then JET/ACE, but I never really looked close.

Tables of several million rows tend to be nothing for ACE/JET and Access, and I would suggest that SQLite would produce similar results, but allow you to get around the 2 gig limitation. I think if the files are pushing the 2 gig limit, then I would consider using  a server based system for the database. However, if the database is not to be multi-user, then again, using a "file" based in-process file data engine like jet or SQLite should not pose any particular performance penalty over that of using a local server based system.

If a network or multiple users come into play, then hands down a server system that runs as a separate process (and thus on separate CPU cores is a better choice).

I have tested SQLite with Access, but not for large files, so I don't know how well it works for large tables. I mean, 5, or 10 million rows will easy fit in a JET database, so it not clear as to how large your datasets are, but they must be rather large if you exceeding JET. SQL Express is free, and allows up to 10 gigs, but you do of course have to setup and run a "server" database on your stand alone computer, and often that's not worth the setup time.

Comment: You can tune sqlite to use [multiple threads](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_threads), mostly used only for sorting results, though.

Answer (score 1):

Switching BE for Access is pretty easy but unless you know how to "handle" the new BE Pros & Cons you won't get very far and you will just add issues to your current ones.
If your main concern is size you can split your data in more that 1 BE (.mdbs,.accdbs) and still stay in the Access ecosystem.
Also you have to take into account that SQLite is more single user oriented so if your are going to use it in a network this will be problematic.A good way to use it if you are the only user of your application is to keep the "real" data in Ms Access and store the "extra" data to a SQLite DB (like documents,photos..etc) .

Answer (score 1):

I guess my answer was very similar John's answer above. Additionally, you can utilize the analyze database tool and double check your tables are normalized. Split the back-end database. Don't store images and photos inside the accdb file and just create links outside database for them. There's numerous things you can perform to reduce size.